# How to see email attachments when replying to an email

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-outlook-2016

When I reply to an email in Outlook 2013, the original email is not accessible (other than the fact my reply email contains the thread). This means, if the original email had an attachment, I can't access it....

Currently, I have to discard the email completely which will then show the original email (including the attachments). I then have to open the relevant attachments or save them to the machine before restarting my response/forward.

Is there a way to see the original email with it's attachments after I start replying or forwarding an email in Outlook 2013/2016

Comment: Forwarding a message in outlook should keep the attachments, but replying will not (I believe it was a design decision).

Comment: @bfhd, yes... thanks... That has nothing to do with the question though.

Comment: This behavior is terrible...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's what I do:

1. While editing the new email, click the "pop-out" button to open the new message in a separate window.
2. Now the original email is available for you to view attachments.

There is a pic of the pop out button on this page : http://www.howtogeek.com/172625/how-to-enable-and-disable-the-separate-message-editing-window-for-replies-in-outlook-2013/

Comment: This doesn't work on 2016...

Comment: I'm using Outlook 2016  and works for me :S  I wonder why we're getting different results

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to show the attachments, a pain in and I am trying to find a way to turn that feature off but until then, you have the thread and you want to respond.

Look for the blue i circle icon your replied to this message link.  up by the heading by your name

Click that link and it will open another search pane with all the threads, a few clicks and all the attachments will show up, annoying, time consuming but the only way I know how to get the attachments for now.

Answer (score 0):

Click on View >Conversation Settings and select >Always Expand Conversations.

That shows you the individual items with accessible attachments but still grouped as a conversation.

Answer (score 0):

In Office 2016, make sure "Show as conversations" is checked on the View Tab. Then next to the email you will see a pop out arrow, click it to see the entire email chain and the attachments you are looking for.